# Copy struct to a pointer multiple times using aligned_malloc and memcpy

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I am trying to copy a struct object to a pointer variable where I have allocated memory using _aligned_malloc and all I want is to copy the struct more than 1 time. If I copy it 1 time it works otherwise it doesn't. This is the snippet of the code:

```
dev_probConfig = (ProbConfig*)_aligned_malloc(N* sizeof(ProbConfig),64);
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) 
{
    memcpy(dev_probConfig + i * sizeof(ProbConfig), h_probConfig, sizeof(ProbConfig));
}
```

What am I doing wrong?! 
My struct doesn't contain padding and its size is 512 bytes.
Thanks.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages and the code should be written differently in each. Please remove the unrelated tag. Also what is `_aligned_malloc`? it is not a standard function. It might be an internal symbol you are not allowed to use from application code. Provide a [mcve]. "My code doesn't work" is not a valid problem description. Read [ask].

Comment: I encourage you to write it as `memcpy(&dev_probConfig[i], h_probConfig, sizeof(ProbConfig));`. That's clearer and guaranteed to handle pointer arithmetic correctly. I assume that  you already declared `h_probConfig` as a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

This is a tricky aspect of pointer arithmetic in C.  Adding 1 to a pointer-to-*T* increments it by `sizeof(T)`, not by 1.  So you should remove the `* sizeof(ProbConfig)` to make this do what you want.

Assuming this is actually C, it would be better style to write this as either:

```
dev_probConfig = _aligned_malloc(N * sizeof(ProbConfig), 64);
for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    memcpy(&dev_probConfig[i], h_probConfig, sizeof(ProbConfig));
```

or, using structure assignment instead of `memcpy`,

```
dev_probConfig = _aligned_malloc(N * sizeof(ProbConfig), 64);
for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    dev_probConfig[i] = h_probConfig;
```

`&dev_probConfig[i]` is the same as `dev_probConfig + i`, but it is clearer, precisely because of this trickiness of pointer arithmetic.

Also, *do not* cast the result of a `malloc`-like function in C.  It is not necessary, and it can hide bugs: for instance, if you forget to include `stdlib.h` in a program that uses `malloc`, the legacy "implicit declaration" rule kicks in and `malloc` is treated as returning an `int` rather than a `void *`. If `int` and `void *` are not the same size (e.g. because `int` is 32 bits wide but pointers are 64 bits wide) this will corrupt the pointer in a way that might not be noticed until your program has to crunch more data than usual.  You will get a warning from the compiler — but only if you don't cast the return value.

(In C++ you have to cast the result of `malloc`-like functions, but in C++ you should be using `std::vector` anyway.  You can use a [custom allocator](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4795/C-Standard-Allocator-An-Introduction-and-Implement) to get a `std::vector` with extra alignment for the array; this *looks* awful complicated but it's really just a lot of boilerplate.)

Comment: what's wrong with
`for (i = 0; i < n; i++) dev_prob_config[i] = h_probConfig;`?
It's the same thing and it's a lot more clear what you want.

Comment: no, I mean what's wrong with directly assigning structures instead of doing the compiler's job trying to optimizie structure assignments with `memcpy()`

Comment: @mfro I wanted to change only the things that really _needed_ changing.  It's true that your version is much simpler, but OP had `memcpy` and there's nothing _wrong_ with doing it that way.

Comment: "Also, do not cast the result of a malloc-like function in C. This can actually hide critical-severity bugs." Why is that?

Comment: @geza Short version: if you forget to include `<stdlib.h>`, in C you are still allowed to call `malloc` but the compiler will treat it as having return type `int` ("implicit declaration") rather than `void *`, and (depending on the ABI) this may cause it to corrupt the returned pointer. With most modern compilers, you will get a warning when this happens, but only if you _don't_ cast the return value.

Comment: @zwol I have tried your solution and it looks like working but then when I allocate more than one time and I run the code without using the second portion of the array I get errors. I want to point out that I am trying to allocate more structs on an array in order to pass them to a OpenCL kernel. And it is not working..

Comment: @LorenzoCucurachi Please ask a new question. In the new question, provide a _complete program_ that we can compile and run for ourselves and watch fail. But make sure it is the _smallest possible complete program_ that demonstrates the problem you are having, and make sure it has no other problems. Also, we need you to tell us _exactly_ what errors you are getting.

Comment: @zwol I cannot share my code as it is part of my job. I can only explain my problem the best I can and provide some code. Would that be ok?

Comment: @LorenzoCucurachi Write a program from scratch that exhibits the same problem, keeping it as small as possible. This might sound like busywork but it's not; you may well discover the problem for yourself in the process. I also recommend you read "[How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)."